# Saving mouse-click coordinates with the CENTER of click.box as origin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write bits of code in an html webpage, so that when the user clicks the mouse within my ClickBox, the X and Y coordinates are saved and then sent to my database.

But for now, the click handler... Here is how far I have got:

```
<body>
    <div id = "ClickBox" style = "left:100px;"> </div>
</body>



<script>
    $( document ).ready( function(e)
    {
            $( '#ClickBox' ).click( function(e)
        {
                alert( e.pageX + ' , ' + e.pageY );
        });
    });
</script>



<style type="text/css">
     #ClickBox { width:640px; height:480px; cursor:pointer; background:#2f2f2f; top:50px; color:#fff; font:bold 12px Arial; }
</style>
```

It works, but displays the click coordinates in a way that is obvious the origin is not the center or top left corner of my ClickBox. How do I modify these snippets, so that regardless of where my ClickBox is located on my webpage, I always get the precise coordinates with the **center** of my **ClickBox** being the coordinate **origin**?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Get the coordinates and measures of your clickbox as well – after that, it’s a couple of simple math operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coordinates relative to top and left.

```
coordX = e.pageX - $('#clickbox').offset().left;
coordY = e.pageY - $('#clickbox').offset().top;
```

To get coordinates with CENTER of Clickbox as origin

```
coordX = e.pageX - $('#clickbox').offset().left - ($('#clickbox').width() * 0.5);
coordY = e.pageY - $('#clickbox').offset().top - ($('#clickbox').height() * 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

e.pageX and a.pageY are the position of four cursor in the page not a specific div.

but you can get the mouse position in the div removing the top and the left distance of your div from the body

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the offset of the div:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T8H9X/)

```
$( '#ClickBox' ).click( function(e){
    var coordX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
        coordY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    alert( coordX + ' , ' + coordY );
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you know why in the demo the coordinates are displayed as integers, whereas in my browser as floating points, with quite a few decimal digits?!

Comment: @enyce12 your code showing alert with coordinates of x and y but i need text area on click and when i save some thing in text area and submit it should save in db and also show in box with some pointer and when hover or click on it shoes that save value.